# Abrir pdf/doc almacenado en sql server usando asp.net y entityframework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, pdf, entity-framework

tengo una aplicación web en la que estoy guardando archivos de tipo pdf o doc en la base de datos en una tabla con un parámetro de tipo "varbinary", sé que no es lo ideal guardar archivos así en la base de datos pero necesito saber como puedo ver ese archivo desde mi navegador web en una nueva pestaña, estuve viendo sobre binaryreader pero no me queda claro aun, agradecería mucho su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
//Obtenemos el byte[]
var bytes = tuEntity.ToByteArrayPropery;
//Limpiamos el response para quitarnos todo el HTML 
Response.Clear()
//Seteamos el content type
//Esta parte debería ser dinámica si tienes más de un tipo
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
//Opcional, seteamos el file name
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyPDF.pdf");
//Escribimos el output
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
//Tambien se puede hacer así
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
//Finalizamos el response
Response.End()
```